# SASS/SCSS django

Tags: django, sass

[PHOTO - show mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhF8.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXCf5.png)

Why got red underline (photo) as some problem in code, is there are some mistake? But it work properly... And the same question to sass in link...

What to do for remove this "mistake".

```
{% load sass_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="{% sass_src 'css/main.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Django Sass</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WORK</h1>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: No, this is just the HTML inspector that does not understand the Django template tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why got red underline (photo) as some problem in code, is there are some mistake?

No, for the first photo there *is* a mistake: you can not use the `{% sass_src … %}` template tag if you don't load it into the scope. So you should add `{% load sass_tags %}`, like you did.

Now the HTML inspector however *thinks* it found a problem: the first line in the *rendered* HTML code should be the first tag, but since `{% load sass_tags %}` will not generate any content, that will be the case.

For some (very) old browsers, there can be problems for the first line being empty and then a line with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so it might be advisable to use:

```
{% load sass_tags %}<!DOCTYPE html>
```

so on the same line, but likely the HTML inspector will still not be happy, but it is not a problem: this is simply the inspector not understanding the `{% load … %}` Django template tag, which is resolved at *server* side.